# Typescript debugger not built into a particular text editor

Tags: debugging

Are there any typescript debuggers with source maps that you don't need a particular text editor to use?

I'm looking for a debugger that isn't built into one particular editor, and that lets you set breakpoints in your original typescript files (not the compiled JS).

As described by jetbrains, this is the functionality I'm after:

> With WebStorm, you set breakpoints in the original TypeScript code instead of the compiled JavaScript that is actually executed. WebStorm recognizes and processes breakpoints in TypeScript using source maps.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/running-and-debugging-typescript.html

I use ndb when debugging node, but as far as I'm aware, it doesn't work with typescript in  this way. Is there anything similar that I can use for typescript?